# How can I create a user input and a log in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I would like to create the game battleship in XNA.
In order to create the game I would like to take user input for the placement of the ships and the plays themselves, and put them in a log for the player to see. I have no problem creating the game itself and the visual aspects, but I dont know how to create a visible user input that will show up later in a log. (I can send a picture of a mockup, but I can't post)

How can I create a user input (as in text based games) and a log?

Comment: you mean like text box? you have to build this, create some texture that looks like textbox, and when click on it to capture what user write and show it on screen.

Comment: I would want the game to function like a text based game. Isn't there a way to use a console/log that is already built?

Comment: you have to create it, here is example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216757/adding-inputbox-like-control-to-xna-game

Comment: He could create a console in a new thread, that takes input and can be used to redifine varaibles in the game. That way there will always be a log, and he won't really need to create anything. That's what I think he's looking for. Lots of old games did this to set up a chat people could use while gaming.

Comment: i found some other solution i think that's what he want: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45107/input-output-console-window-in-xna