# C# and XNA with user input number

Tags: c#, xna

I am dealing with a simple game under C# and XNA. I need a textbox that user can input number(0-1000), then this number can be used in the code. I saw many long example here such as [Adding inputbox-like control to XNA game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216757/adding-inputbox-like-control-to-xna-game), 
but what I need is much easier than it. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Does the application need to run on the Xbox? If not, you can just create windows forms windows within your application.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, not in Xbox only in windows. Could you give me example or tell me where I can find it please?

Comment: How about building a little Slider Widget which the user can slide up and down to change a value between 0 and 1000?